# Tab key not editing text

Tags: edit-mode, text-object

Usually, when I edit templates, I can just press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and I can edit the text. Suddenly, when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, this happens:

[image: The Text shows all sorts of dots and shapes]

Comment: That text object has been converted to mesh. It is no longer editable as text, it needs to be recreated as a new text object.

Comment: @Timaroberts how?

Comment: Please don't use all caps when asking questions. It is considered yelling... no need for that.

Comment: You cannot return this object to text, you would need to make a new text object.

Comment: @cegaton sorry my bad

Comment: Guys how do I make a text layer that is perfectly synced like the mesh layer? Or do I need to replace it? If I need to replace it, how do I?

Comment: @TheBoyWonder once you convert the text object into mesh, you cannot amend it as a text, you can copy the text object using shift+D and move it to another layer using (M) and choosing a layer, in case you need to revert to text, you'll have your back up object, it would e easier to describe what you're trying to achieve in a new question

Answer (score 2):

One of the drawbacks of using "template" files created by someone else is that you have no control over them. Whatever choices the creator made are now part of the file.

The text in question is not editable as text anymore because it has been converted to a mesh. **There is no operation to turn a mesh back to text**.

You would need to create a new text object that fits your needs, and then copy or link to it whatever other attributes or animation the original mesh was using.

Something to be asked in a different question.